# how to start using version conrol

Tags: version-control

I've always developed by working on a live server modifying the files direclty off the server. I am really wanting to break the horrible habit and start using version control and applying patches when fully tested.

I should also explain how i work. I always wite code bit by bit, testing how each part works. I'll throw up a quick visual prototype, and then start "filling in" the missing pieces, saving and testing all along the way.

My question though is how can i test the code and how do I release it. Should i have a live server that duals as a repository so that whenever i save the file it commits to the  repository and is ready for me to test? Then when its all done and tested copy the repository and upload it to the live server? I'm not really sure how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a source code repository/server.

We use [Git](http://git-scm.com/), though we've also used [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) in the past, in a similar fashion.

You will have at least two web servers:

- Production
- Development

On the development server, you will make your changes. Test on development also. When you are ready to go live, you will commit the changes from the development server to the repository. You will then pull the changes from the repository to the production server.

Alternatively, you might have three web servers:

- Production
- Development
- Test

Here, instead of testing on development, you will test on Test. This will allow you to keep developing while you're testing a particular branch.

Comment: This looks good. But im beginning to wonder why use souce control at all except so i can keep track of revisions. I'm just a sole developer.

Comment: Ok, i want to go with this because i like the idea of having a site i can develop on,and then a site that i can have a few people come test. My question is this: how will all this work with different databases?

Comment: You will most likely have a copy of the database for each instance of the server as well. The development and test databases can be copies of the live database, with any schema changes applied to them via a script. When you go live, apply the script to production as well. After you go live with the changes, your test environment can be used to recreate bugs without affecting live data.

Comment: But what about config files? They would have to be different for each server.

Comment: You could have all config files exactly the same, except for one tiny one that designates which server it is (not checked into source control), and you use branching code in your config file. That's how we do it. We started out with different config files (not in source control), which is probably easy for you. With many developers and servers, it was easier to put them in source control and branch them in code.

Comment: I'm using cakePHP. It has all config values in a single file. Including the value to turn on and off debugging. I change that file often. How can I make sure that the database values are not over written on a commit?

Comment: I don't understand, "database values are not overwritten". Changes don't get applied until you pull them to the server that you want updated. You can commit all you want. Also, I don't know cakePHP, but maybe you don't put the config file in source control.

Comment: I guess I could just leave that out and just manually update the config file when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/). I recommend using SVN because of 2 things:

- You have no previous experience with a VCS. SVN has an easier ramp-up compared to Git. Git has a higher learning curve, but it is more powerful than SVN once mastered.
- You are working on a single developer (ie, only you) project. You will only fully realize the power of Git is when you have multiple developers working on the same project (since it's cheap to do branches and merges in Git), or when you have limited access to the 'central' repo (Git is a Distributed VCS, therefore, the whole repository is in your computer).

That being said, you should probably separate your live environment and your test environment. Then, the process of releasing a new code will be something in the line of:

1. Make changes locally
2. Test locally
3. Once done, commit to SVN
4. Export the code (`svn export`) and deploy to the test server
5. Test in the test server
6. Deploy the same code exported in step 4 to the live environment

Comment: My development computer alreay has so much junk runing on it. Is there a way to remove the test locally step?. Also, could you explain the reason for testing both locally AND on a test server? And by the way, +1 for actually answering to the actual question I asked.

Comment: By 'test locally', I really meant 'working on the code until you get it right'. And then, you can think of the 'test in the test server' step as a black box testing ("now that I have the code deployed in the test server, when I feed it with a particular input, does it behave as I expected?")

Comment: I'd suggest cleaning up the code base and importing it to a VCS sooner than later. Then, you can easily track every changes that you make because it always has a history in the VCS.

Comment: Question though. Why do i ned to keep a history of my changes if im the sole developer?

Comment: Because I can guarantee that someday you will look at a piece of code and wonder 'Why did I make that change?' or 'Why was it done this way?'

Comment: A history of changes comes in really handy when you decide to make a major change, get halfway through, and figure out that you went the wrong way. You can then start over again by reverting to one of the historical versions. It also allows you to try something you're not sure of, and throw away that attempt (or keep it later) at any point. You can also keep many back versions, so you can go back to the way something was at any point in time.

Comment: I guess it would be a good thing to have when wanting to test something radically different. I could just create a branch, work on it, and throw it away if needed.

Answer (score -1):

use svn.  install your own copy (open source) or some hosts ie. Dreamhost has one you can use.  at least this is what i do.

tried hosting my own svn but it was not worth the trouble... at least for me.

Comment: Im not asking what type of version control to use. That is irrelavant ( unless it makes a difference in the ease of testing and releasing)  but rather how to go about using it in my development cycle.